# Why will this not send to the channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I want to send the warn to the user-set log channel, but it says NoneType has no attribute send. But, thing is
it's CLEARLY defined!

EDIT: I found out why. It's selecting the first query it gets from the database, so if the server_id from a different server's table is above another table, it won't work, because you're not in that server

```py
        cursor.execute("SELECT channel_id FROM logchannel")
        result1 = cursor.fetchone()
        if result1 is not None:
            channel_id = result1[0]
            channel1 = discord.utils.get(server.channels, id=channel_id)
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} was warned for {reason}")
        channel_id = result1[0]
        channel1 = discord.utils.get(server.channels, id=channel_id)
        await channel1.send(f"{member.mention} has been warned by {user.mention} for {reason}.")
        cursor.execute('SELECT warnings FROM warninglog WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s', (user_id, guild_id))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            warnings = 1
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO warninglog (warnings, name, user_id, guild_id ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)',
                           (warnings, name, user_id, guild_id))
            conn.commit()
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to highlight the error in particular, post less of code (only the relevant part, and more if asked) and state your goal clearly? Thanks!

Comment: discord.utils.get returns None if it cant find what its looking for. Is it possible your trying to find an int with a string or something